# How to implement "preset" and "crf" value using ffmpeg videokit library?

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to compress the video using ffmpeg videokit library in android.

```
public static String compressVideo(String videoPath){
        String POSTFIX = "compressed.mp4";
        String compressVideoPath = videoPath.replace(".mp4",POSTFIX);
        final VideoKit videoKit = new VideoKit();
        final Command command = videoKit.createCommand()
                .overwriteOutput()
                .inputPath(videoPath)
                .outputPath(compressVideoPath)
                .customCommand("-ss 1 -t 180")
                .customCommand("-crf "+"28")
                .customCommand("-preset faster")
                .copyVideoCodec()
                .experimentalFlag()
                .build();
        command.execute();
        return compressVideoPath;
    }
```

But the crf and preset is giving error.

Comment: Share the error detail if possible

Comment: Its not giving error , but its not creating any video at compressed path,but if we remove crf and preset value it creates compressed video at that path.